# Linearizations induced by the trivial one?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

Let $k$ be a field, algebraically closed for simplicity. $G=GL_{n+1}(k),$ $X=\mathbb{P}_k^n$ and consider the action
$G\times X\rightarrow X$ given by $(g,x)\mapsto gx$ (thus induced by usual left action of $G$ on $\bar k^n$).

Let $L=X\times \mathbb{A}_k^1$ be the trivial line bundle on $X$ (corresponding to the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^n}$) with trivial $G$-linearization, i.e.

$$G\times L\rightarrow L, (g,(x,t))\mapsto (gx,t).$$

Now my question:

I have seen it written that the linearization given above induces linearizations on the twisting bundles $L(l)$ for all $l\in\mathbb{N},$ i.e. the bundles corresponding to the twisted sheaves $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^n}(l).$ Could anyone please explain how this works, exactly?

I am asking this because I want to understand the action of $G$ on the spaces $$H^0(X,L(l))\cong H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_k^n}(l))\cong k[X_0,\ldots,X_n]_l.$$
of global sections.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The answer to the last part of your question is very simple: the action of $G$ on $\mathbf{P}^n$ yields the dual action on $H^0(O(1))$, and this in turn gives an action on each $H^0(O(n))$, i.e. by linear changes of variables in polynomials of degree n.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more explicit the first part of your answer? For some reason I am not able to work out the action on $H^0(O(1))$ nor do I find any good reference where this is explained explicitly.

Comment: The point is that the action of G on $P^n$ really comes from an action on the underlying vector space $k^{n+1}$. Now $H^0(O(1))$ is just the dual space of that vector space, so $G$ acts by duality: if $l \in H^0(O(1))$ is a linear form, then $g \in G$ sends it to the form $g \cdot l$ defined by $(g \cdot l)(x) = l(g(x))$.

Comment: So that was the question. I read in several books that you define the action of $G$ on $H^0(X,L)$ by
$$(g.s)(x):= g.s(g^{-1}.x),$$
so I'd guess to make the action you wrote down a left action again it should be $l(g^{-1}(x))$ in your terms.

Anyway I was not sure whether or not in the case of $L=\mathcal{O}(1)$ we would somehow have to take into account an action of $G$ on the ground field but from your formula I take it we don't.

Comment: Oops, you're right that it should be g^{-1} rather than g.